# What makes or breaks a solo AP Mid?

Tags: league-of-legends

What makes a good AP Solo Mid? What should you train for, and what kind of items, runes, and mastery trees Should I use?

I want to try out for a AP Solo Mid position on a team, but am new to League of Legends and need to know what to practice to improve my game.

Does anyone know of a team that is willing to recruit and train new players?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, practice your last hitting. That is the single most important thing in any lane role in League of Legends.

Pick a champion that seems right for you. Right now, the popular ones are Kassadin, Ahri, Sion, kennen, Ryze, Karthus, Morgana, etc. After you pick your champion and are ready to practice, learn their auto attack animation and get comfortable with it. You can push A then click on a minion to force your character to attack a certain minion the millisecond your champion can autoattack.

As for masteries, I would run 21/9/0 grabbing all the AP/damage you can in the Offensive tree, as well as magic resist in Defense with the extra health. Runes should be Magic Penetration reds/marks, Ability Power per level yellows/seals, and Ability Power per level blues/glyphs with flat AP quints.

Your build usually starts with boots and 3 health potions, as the mobility to farm, evade ganks/harassment, and harass back is super duper important, as well as it enhances your ability to go gank other lanes. And as a tip, **always** build to win your lane. If you start taking too much damage and keep getting CC'ed by your opponent (or their jungle) and there is nothing you can do, grab merc treads for boots.

The magic resist and CC reduction is well worth giving up extra damage. but I'm going to go my usual build from farming and a normal not incredibly fed game. I usually go 2 Doran's Rings into magic pen boots, into a Deathcap, Void Staff, and then defensive items or more AP damage to either nuke harder or to help keep yourself alive.

If you happen to get super fed, go 3 Doran's Rings, into magic pen boots, Deathcap, Void Staff, into more AP. But these builds are just the normal AP route. Different champs call for different builds.

To put a short version on this:

- Practice your last hitting, this is the most important thing to do in your lane.
- Learn your champions abilities, in and out, as knowing what does what will help you out.
- Watch your minimap and if you feel safe, steal their wraiths to help get yourself ahead. careful though, only do this if you are sure their jungle is nowhere near them, as you do not want to die for the 60 extra gold.
- Did i mention practice last hitting? yes, its this important.
- Watch for your jungler to also give you the blue buff, as unlimited mana is always a good thing for an AP mid.
- Look up a guide. google a guide for a set champion, and build off of that. theres plenty out there that give their advice on what they build for certain champs, what runes, masteries and what skills they level at certain levels.

Those are the things that go through my mind when I solo mid as an AP. I hope its not too confusing and gives good pointers.

Comment: Out of curiousity whats your elo? this doesnt seem like someone who would play in high rated elo, especially with the 2 or 3 doran rings part. and your masteries clearly show how you dont seem to get blue very often.

Comment: I'd agree: Doran's Rings into Deathcap is not very common in the current meta. Not even mentioning RoA is very weird.

Comment: im just saying thats what i do for a pure ap build. every champ has a different way of doing things. just like on gragas or annie i do that because their damage is almost unparallelled. and rod of ages is questionable for me on some ap mids. its not required on all of them.

Answer (score 8):

I disagree with last hitting (*added this: Last hitting is the technique of hitting a creep just before it dies, without doing any previous damage to it) making or breaking an ap mid. AP champions tend to have problems last hitting, especially near tower(You don't want to miss creep kills due to your tower). So it works great for champions like morgana to push her lane with and area of effect ability like tormented soil.

In my opinion things like this are good to focus on (not in any particular order):

**High CS**: Kill as many minions as possible. Try to aim for about 200 cs by 20 minutes. You can maximize your cs by taking wraiths when your minions are by the enemy tower. When pushing to the enemy tower, you also don't want to stand up by their tower to poke the tower without safety from wards. Also, by pushing your lane, it gives you the chance to kill wraith camps/leave lane to gank side lanes.

**Map Awareness**: This is probably the most important if you want to live or die. You are in the center of the map with the least distance to travel to any lane. If a side lane has an opening for a gank, you should take advantage of it. If an enemy is missing from a side lane, you might be in danger, an ally might be in danger, or an objective is being taken. Wards can help you stay alive.

**Counterpick**: Some AP Mids work better against other AP Mids, use lolpro.com which is a website guide with proven counters from pro LoL players.

### Runes

- Magic Penetration is the most popular choice for marks.
- AP per Level or Mana Regen per level is a popular choice for seals. (Some AP Mids take health per level)
- AP per level or Mana Regen per level is a popular choice for glyphs.
- Movement speed, ap flats, or ap per level is a popular choice for quintessences.

### Masteries:

21/0/9 Fares well always, since you want to maximize your damage as ap mid.

### Decisions that will break an AP mid:

- Giving first blood
- Not calling 'mia' or 'ss', not ganking your side lanes/assisting jungler.
- Not getting blue buff when you need it
- Low CS compared to your rival.

**Items: (I obtained these item recommendations from observing professional play, summarizing guides from professional players):**

**Starter:** Boots + 3 pots. This is the most effective to start with since with it, you can avoid getting ganked, you can chase, you can harass, and you have potions. It is more effective than doran's ring because low level skills don't benefit as much from the extra ap from doran's ring. The mana regen from doran's ring will probably get you enough mana for 2-5 spells before you buy again, but you might lose health because you can't escape trades with the enemy player.

*Doran's Ring:* Most commonly bought 1-2 times, usually not when a rod of ages is rushed.

*Rabadon's Deathcap:* The core ap item for any ap champion,

*Will of the Ancients:* A strong, rushed sustain item for Kennen, Morgana, Cassiopeia, Ahri, Vladimir, Swain, Malzahar and Viktor. Usully rushed after boots.

*Rod of Ages:* Strong, rushed health/ap item on Annie, Swain, Malzahar, Kassadin, Anivia, Morgana, Veigar, Zilean, Orianna, Galio, Gragas and Viktor. Gives a good amount of health and mana with a very fair 80 AP.

*Zhonya's Hourglass:* Strong item that has synergy with Morgana's ult and Kennen's ult that makes it worth rushing. Works well on all AP carries as a defensive item.

Comment: `I disagree with last hitting making or breaking an ap mid`, but then the first thing you mention is `Kill as many minions as possible. Aim for about 200 cs by 200 minutes.` (also I think you mean 20 minutes, not 200).

Comment: Actually last hitting correctly will never let your tower (or very rarely) steal stuff from you. and being mid = if you push = gg from the enemy jungler. If you push with aoe and your enemy is good at controlling the minions = he will keep the minion wave close to his tower which goes back to gg from enemy jungler if you try to go get more cs. Usually you want to push your lane when you want to either B or go gank, this is very very effective. As a clear example you can see at how morde got raped for doing what you just said in the last month world finals.

Comment: Last hitting is the technique of hitting a creep just before it dies, without doing any previous damage to it. This allows the lane to push towards your own tower.  Often times for ap mids, last hitting is difficult near the tower because the ap doesn't have enough base damage to "last hit".

Comment: Last hitting is the technique of dealing the final hit to a creep. There is multiple last-hitting mode: Last hit pushing (you want to have creeps with different level of health to avoid losing CS), last hit balancing (you want to have creeps with the same level of health to kill them with AoE spell) or last hit freezing (dealing only the final hits to allow creep pushing). For example you can read : http://kassadin.blogspot.fr/2009/11/last-hitting.html . I can add there is also a tower last hitting, where you need to know when to deal damage to use tower shots at your advantage.

Answer (score 1):

> An AP Carry is a champion that does damage with ability power versus attack damage.  It is also a champion that is responsible for 'carrying' the game or doing the most damage in a team fight.  Think of it as the 'star player' in a team game.  The quarterback in football, the striker in hockey or the shooter in soccer.  The goal of the rest of the team members is to make sure to 'support' or make the Carry shine. 
>   AP Carries do damage with Ability Power, this Ability Power is built-in with the types of spells that they have.

Check out this guide for more info: http://www.lolpro.com/guides/game-play/197-how-to-ap-carry

Answer (score 0):

Last hitting is HUGE, probably your main focus. Items are different depending on the champ but a good core item is will of the ancients for the spell vamp for sustain. Get wards and get some vision to prevent you from getting ganked.

Answer (score 0):

Outfarming your opponent is always good, but really **map awareness** is key. By having good map awareness and ward control, you can avoid ganks (usually, ganks happen in mid), roam, take enemy wraiths, and farm until late game.

Answer (score 0):

Very few people know how important it is to last hit minions when they start. Items depends on situation, but you want to start with boots and 3 pots to get away from ganks and harassing.

As for runes, it can vary depending on person.

For masteries, I recommend 21/0/9.

Answer (score 0):

**Smartcasting** is your friend. Like it, learn it, love it. It will never steer you wrong when you become accusmted to it.

[YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6GEagYbiCc) about it.